# Android mediaplayer not working

Tags: android

I have created an activity which receives messages realtime. Sometimes the message is just a notification, other times the message leads to a yes/no alert dialog pop up.
I wanted to create a 10 second sound notification for this so I declared in the class.
I made mediaplayer global so as to not create it everytime i need to play sound.

```
final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

I set datasource in activity oncreate

```
try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getBaseContext(), defaultRingtoneUri);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then in when i receive the message I do in onnewintent

```
 try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    }
            }
        }, 10000);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Finally to stop alert sound when alertdialog is clicked i have done

```
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked
                        response = "1";
                        Log.v("Yes button clicked", response);
                        //some code
                        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        //No button clicked
                        response = "-1";
                        Log.v("No button clicked", response);
                        //some code
                        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
```

I was testing this till yest. on xperia p with expected behaviour all along. No issues at all. Today i got a new lava iris (it has a smaller ROM 512M). On first message it plays the sound but afterwards i get an error of IOexception on prepare with `status=0xFFFFFF8E`

Any ideas on what am i doing wrong here? I will be open to changing the implementation if a cleaner way is there for this purpose.

```
 01-01 09:53:54.813: D/YourActivity(15988): onNewIntent is called!
 01-01 09:53:54.816: W/System.err(15988): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFF8E
01-01 09:53:54.818: W/System.err(15988):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
01-01 09:53:54.822: W/System.err(15988):    at com.example.delmole.OrderActivity.onNewIntent(OrderActivity.java:309)
01-01 09:53:54.822: W/System.err(15988):    at      android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnNewIntent(Instrumentation.java:1156)
01-01 09:53:54.823: W/System.err(15988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2464)
01-01 09:53:54.823: W/System.err(15988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performNewIntents(ActivityThread.java:2477)
01-01 09:53:54.823: W/System.err(15988):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleNewIntent(ActivityThread.java:2486)
01-01 09:53:54.823: W/System.err(15988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:162)
01-01 09:53:54.824: W/System.err(15988):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1435)
01-01 09:53:54.824: W/System.err(15988):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
01-01 09:53:54.824: W/System.err(15988):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
01-01 09:53:54.824: W/System.err(15988):    at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
01-01 09:53:54.825: W/System.err(15988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 09:53:54.825: W/System.err(15988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-01 09:53:54.826: W/System.err(15988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
01-01 09:53:54.826: W/System.err(15988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-01 09:53:54.827: W/System.err(15988):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please, put the full error in LogCat

Comment: what is the OrderActivity? Can You tell us what is in line 309 there?

Comment: line 309 is mediaPlayer.prepare(); i've already given the code above for that in the try block

Comment: I strongly recommend using SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer for better Performance and (from a Programers Point of view) better Usability.

Answer (score 0):

in your code the statement - mediaPlayer.prepare(); is causing the error because mediaplayer object is already prepared when the notification sound is played first time.

Try placing this statement in onCreate method so that this statement is executed only once not every time when onnewintent is called.

Another possible solution is -

write mediaPlayer.reset(); before mediaPlayer.prepare(); in onnewintent method

It will change the state of mediaplayer object to idle and there will be no problem in prepare statement.

Comment: added prepare in the oncreate. now i only have .start and .stop calls when i receive messages. but now it gives me an erro saying start called in state 0; error(-38,0)

Comment: use mediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); instead of mediaPlayer.prepare();

Comment: doesn't work. instead of stopping i am pausing and starting now. That seems to work as of now.

Comment: You can not prepare mediaplayer object after calling .stop() method. you have to re-instantiate mediaplayer object and follow all methods which you used earlier before calling .start() method. And your project is working by using .pause() method then make sure to call .stop() method in onDestroy() method of the Activity.